# Error: Illegal namespace for attribute declaration: http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance

Tags: xml, wsdl, soapui, sap-ariba

I am trying to create a new SOAP project in SOAPUI thru importing a wsdl. The initial part of wsdl looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="http://sap.com/xi/SAPGlobal20/Global" name="BusinessPartnerSUITEBulkReplicateRequestIn" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://sap.com/xi/SAPGlobal20/Global" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<wsdl:types>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="nil"/>
</xs:schema>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://sap.com/xi/SAP_BS_FND/MDG/Global2" targetNamespace="http://sap.com/xi/SAP_BS_FND/MDG/Global2" xmlns:ns1="http://ariba.com/xi/SupplierManagement" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="unqualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://ariba.com/xi/SupplierManagement" xmlns:tns="http://ariba.com/xi/SupplierManagement" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="unqualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" xmlns:mdg="http://sap.com/xi/SAP_BS_FND/MDG/Global2" xmlns:sapg20="http://sap.com/xi/SAPGlobal20/Global" xmlns:sm="http://ariba.com/xi/SupplierManagement" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<xs:import namespace="http://sap.com/xi/SAP_BS_FND/MDG/Global2"/>
<xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
<xs:element type="tns:BPSUITEBulkRplctConfMsg" name="BusinessPartnerSUITEBulkReplicateConfirmationMessage"/>
<xs:element type="tns:BPSUITEBulkRplctReqMsg" name="BusinessPartnerSUITEBulkReplicateRequestMessage"/>
<xs:element type="tns:BPSUITERplctConfMsg" name="BusinessPartnerSUITEReplicateConfirmationMessage"/>
<xs:element type="tns:BPSUITERplctReqMsg" name="BusinessPartnerSUITEReplicateRequestMessage"/>
<xs:complexType name="BPSUITEBulkRplctReqMsg">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element type="tns:BusinessDocumentMessageHeader" name="MessageHeader"/>
<xs:element type="tns:BPSUITERplctReqMsg" name="BusinessPartnerSUITEReplicateRequestMessage" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

I am getting an error:

> Error: Illegal namespace for attribute declaration: http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open the path [`https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance`](https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance) in a webbrowser, you will get this message:

> XML Schema instance namespace
> [...]
> This schema should never be used as such: the XML Schema Recommendation forbids the declaration of attributes in this namespace

This should explain your error.
To fix it, look for any attribute definitions with the prefix `xsi:` or, more likely:

Because you defined an `xs:schema` with a `targetNamespace` like

```
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="nil"/>
</xs:schema>
```

either remove the attribute or better, change this namespace.
This is most likely the problem.